# Importing a component from containers (From outside of the scope)

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure

I'm quite new to react and am having some troubles with this basic problem.

From HomeLander.js - How can I import a Button, and a P? They are, as expected, not in the same scope. Is there a neat way to do this?

My directories are structured in this way:

- Components/

  - Button/

    - index.js
  - P/

    - index.js
- Containers/

  - HomeLander/

    - index.js
- Index.js ("Main" JS file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
import Button from '../../Components/Button'; (given Button component is default export)
import { Button } from '../../Components/Button'; (if Button component is not default export)
```

Same way with 'P'